# Paginate query result with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, pagination

I have a fully working pagination with get method. I get the results from my query and the page is changed when the variable pagination changes on URL. I recently changed the site to ajax and now I can't get the clicked page value from URL

I have a form with some inputs that I use to generate the query and a ajax structure that connects to the PHP file and put the result on a div

My php file:

```
  //items per page
  $quantidade = 30;
  //actual page
  $pagina     = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
  $inicio     = ($quantidade * $pagina) - $quantidade;
  $sql .= " LIMIT " . $inicio . " , " . $quantidade ;

  $qr  = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

  echo "<table id='tab_vendas' border='1' width='100%'>";
  echo "<tr><td>Data</td><td>Loja</td><td>Total (AKZ)</td><td>Total (USD)</td><td>Multicaixa</td><td>Saidas</td><td>Visa</td></tr>";

  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qr);
  if($num_rows > 0){
    while($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)){
          echo "<tr><td>" . $ln['data']."</td>"; 
          echo "<td>" . $ln['loja']."</td>"; 
          echo "<td>" . $ln['totalkz']."</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $ln['totaldollar']."</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $ln['multicaixa']."</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $ln['saidas']."</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $ln['visa']."</td></tr>"; 
    }
  }else{
       echo "Não foram encontrados registos";
  }
echo"</table></div>";



  //total
  $sqlTotal   = "SELECT id FROM vendas";
  $qrTotal    = mysql_query($sqlTotal) or die(mysql_error());
  $numTotal   = mysql_num_rows($qrTotal);

  $totalPagina= ceil($numTotal/$quantidade);

   $exibir = 3;
   $anterior  = (($pagina - 1) == 0) ? 1 : $pagina - 1;
   $posterior = (($pagina+1) >= $totalPagina) ? $totalPagina : $pagina+1;

   echo "<div id='paginacao'><a href='?pagina=1'>Primeira</a> | ";
   echo "<a href=\"?pagina=$anterior\"><<</a> | ";       

   for($i = $pagina-$exibir; $i <= $pagina-1; $i++){
            if($i > 0)
             echo '<a href="?pagina='.$i.'"> '.$i.' </a>';
  }

   echo '<a href="?pagina='.$pagina.'"><strong>['.$pagina.']</strong></a>';       

   for($i = $pagina+1; $i < $pagina+$exibir; $i++){
            if($i <= $totalPagina)
            echo '<a href="?pagina='.$i.'"> '.$i.' </a>';
  }

  echo " | <a href=\"?pagina=$posterior\">>></a> | ";
  echo "  <a href=\"?pagina=$totalPagina\">Ultima</a></div>";
```

My big question is how can I get the actual page value and how to know what button the user clicked.

I tried to change the  link's to a submit button with form attribute that send the form again and run all code again but I can't figured out how to pass the clicked button value.

```
echo " | <input type='submit' form='filtros' name='$posterior' value='>>'>";
echo "  <input type='submit' form='filtros' name='$totalPagina' value='Ultima'></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify your code to make this work as it was when the pages where links.

```
      <a class="page" href="url.com?parameter=value&parameter2=value2">pageNumber</a>
```

javscript code is:

```
      $('.a.page').on('click', function() {
          var url = $(this).attr(href);
          $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: url,
              success: function(response) {
                  $('selector to the container you wish to put the data').html(response.data)
              }
          });
      })
```

In your php yous should echo json_encode your data

```
    echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
```